# Create directory on SourceForge from remote script

Tags: scp, sourceforge

We upload releases of [Kunagi](http://kunagi.org) on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kunagi/files/). Since every release contains multiple files we create a directory for each release. The upload is done by a `scp` command. But we have to create the new directory first. We use the SourceForge website to create it. Is there a way to create the directory from command line?

Comment: Could you please confirm this works for you ? I cant get the `rsync` to work here.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that if you used a 1 to 1 directory structure on your computer, then you could use scp with -r and get the directory automatically created:

```
scp -r some/path/1.0.1 sourceforge.net:/some/path/.
```

Then `1.0.1` is created automatically by scp with the correct command (not the mkdir command line function which is refused but the file transfer command, see [8.4. Creating and Deleting Directories](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13#section-8.4).)