# How to create directory on SourceForge from REST API?

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I have a script for creating folder on SourceForge from terminal, using cURL and REST API.

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383890/create-directory-on-sourceforge-from-remote-script), how to do it with REST API and cURL?

SourceForge have [their documentation of this](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Using%20the%20Release%20API/#making-the-request), but I don't understand much of modifying the request.

Thank you.